# How to sort PHP loop without page refresh using JQUERY

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post, submit

I am trying to send variables using ajax to php page so when I click a button, the sent variable will update to the page without refreshing it.

I have a button called #toshow and when clicked, it will send `?show=okay` as a post.

```
$('#toshow' ).click( function( e ) {
  $.post('?show=okay')
  .done(function(data) {
  });
});
```

and on my php

```
if(isset($_POST['show']) && $_POST['show']) {
  echo $_POST['show'];
}
```

I click the button, but it doesn't show the text 'okay'.
What else do I need to add to make this work?

Thank you!

Comment: You need to fill in the code in the `.done()` callback to take the data and place it wherever it's needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever you print with `echo` in PHP wil be available (if no error occurs) in the JavaScript `data` variable in the callback of `.done()` function. So you need to implement this callback to display the returned text where you need it to be displayed.

Example:

```
.done(function(data) {
    document.write(data);
});
```

Also, the way you send the `show` parameter to the server (as a part of URL) is a GET method, not POST. If you want to use the POST method, pass the data as the second argument of the `$.post()` function:

```
$.post('', {
    show: 'okay'
})
    .done(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are sending "show" variable in query part of URL, then, you must retrieve it from $_GET global variable ... check ...

```
$('#toshow' ).click( function( e ) {
  $.post('', {"show": "okay"})
  .done(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
  });
});
```

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/#jQuery-post-url-data-success-dataType